# Does Sirius Black have a middle name?

Tags: harry-potter, names

Both Sirius Black and his brother Regulus Arcturus Black are named after some of [the brightest stars on the sky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_brightest_stars#List). Given that connection, and given that they are brothers, I guess it is fair to assume that Sirius too had a middle name just like RAB.

Is this middle name mentioned anywhere in the books, or in a JKR interview? Or does the book or JKR explicitly say that Sirius does *not* have a middle name?

Edit: Just noticed [Bellatrix](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?protocol=html&Ident=Bellatrix&NbIdent=1&Radius=10&Radius.unit=arcmin&CooFrame=FK5&CooEpoch=2000&CooEqui=2000&output.max=all&o.catall=on&output.mesdisp=N&Bibyear1=1983&Bibyear2=2005&Frame1=FK5&Frame2=FK4&Frame3=G&Equi1=2000.0&Equi2=1950.0&Equi3=2000.0&Epoch1=2000.0&Epoch2=1950.0&Epoch3=2000.0), in addition to [Regulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulus) [Arcturus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcturus) and [Sirius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius).

Comment: This _Naming your Kids after Stellar Objects_ is apparently a Black family thing: _Andromeda_ (Tonks) or _Draco_ and his son _Scorpius_ (Malfoy) use constellations.

Comment: Yes, Lee. Sirius Lee Black.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens seriously?

Comment: Sirius Jay Black?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Unknown.**

As far as I know, this is not addressed either way in any of:

- the books
- J.K. Rowling interviews
- Pottermore

Nor do any depictions of the Black family tree, either in the films or [a version drawn by J.K. Rowling in 2006](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/blackfamilytree.html) make any mention of Sirius’s middle name. (Note that this is not proof that he does *not* have a middle name, as his brother is listed as “Regulus” on both, but he does have a middle name.)

Answer (score 7):

It's a tradition in some Aristocratic families to name the first born son after the child's father and the second born son after the child's paternal grandfather. Regulus and Sirius' grandfather's name is -you guessed it- Arcturus, hence Regulus Arcturus Black. I've seen it relatively common in fanon to have Sirius' full name written as Sirius Orion Black.

This is not corroborated anywhere in J.K. Rowling's writings or interviews, but -as far as I've seen- is a relatively consistent method across the fandom.

Comment: were this true, that would make Sirius' initials S.O.B., which would be quite unfortunate for him. ;)

Answer (score 4):

According to http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/blackfamilytree.html, the Black family tree drawn by J. K Rowling, Sirius Black has no middle name. However, if one takes into account the previous Sirius Blacks in the family (it is apparently a common name), Sirius would be Sirius Black III (the third). This is also mentioned occasionally across fansites and wikias, so it may not be accurate, just a logical guess/presumption.

Answer (score -1):

It's Sirius Orion Black. Just like his brother Regulus Arcturus Black. Arcturus Black was, by extension, the grandfather of Sirius and Regulus. And Orion Black the eldest son of Arcturus Black III and Melania Macmillan. He married his second cousin, Walburga Black, and the he is the father of Sirius and Regulus Black. And as we all know Walburga is also a Black that is why they don't really have a middle name. But they use the name of there grandparents and father to be there middle name

Comment: DO you have a source for this?

Comment: The speculation that it might be Orion, and why, was already made in [reledihs’s answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72837), so the only useful addition would be a canon source.